# Python program doesn't run in shell script in docker container when i redirect the output

Tags: python, linux, bash, docker, rasa-core

In the docker container I provide a shell script entry point which is as following

```
#!/bin/bash
cat ./bot_domain.yml
cat ./first.yml
python -m rasa_core.train --domain ./domain.yml -s ./stories.md --out ./models &> output.txt
echo "done"
```

I am training a model using shell in docker. The program takes around a minute to execute but when I redirect the output logs of training to

```
output.txt
```

It doesn't seem to execute and goes to the next shell command immediately.
If I don't redirect output logs to txt file it seems to be working fine.
as below

```
python -m rasa_core.train --domain ./domain.yml -s ./stories.md --out ./models
```

I tried executing the same shell script on local machine without docker, it seems to be properly redirecting the output logs. Only in docker it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is the directory where `output.txt` is written writable for the current user?

Comment: Is it relevant that your program uses Python? If not, [edit] your question to reduce its scope, in order to get closer to something like a [mcve].

Comment: Flip your redirection operator around: `>&` (for bash) instead of `&>`. The latter one puts the program in the background, then redirects stdout to the file.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer yeah I guess because other commands' outputs are being redirected to the same file properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following was my command in the docker file

```
CMD ["sh", "run.sh"]
```

I changed the command in the dockerfile from shell to bash and it seemed to worked, by searching I found out that bash has some extra functionalities that the simple shell command lacks.

```
CMD ["/bin/bash", "run.sh"]
```